# Not able to install Lubuntu!

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, lubuntu, mbr

I'm trying to install (dual-boot) Windows 10 and Lubuntu 18.04 Alternate 64-bit. But when I reach the step where we install GRUB, it asks me if I would like to install it on the MBR (Master Boot Record) but it doesn't detect any OS, even though I have Windows 10 installed. Fast Boot and Secure boot are off.  When I select not to install it on the MBR, my laptop directly boots to Windows 10. What should I do? I am using a USB pen drive to do it. The installation was successfully complete. I have done it twice, nothing happens. HELP GUYS!!!!!!!!!

P.S. - It shows the warning that allowing to edit the MBR without the OS being detected may make it temporarily unbootable. But we can manually fix this. If you can't find the solution, tell me how to configure GRUB to get Windows 10 too. I'll install it in the MBR.

Comment: Why are you using the alternate ISO?  You surely aren't trying to install this on a box with less than 768MB of RAM (the use case of the alternate ISO, where there isn't enough RAM during *live* operation to also run `ubiquity` installer). The alternate ISO hasn't had any updates since 2018-April (nor will it get any more), so it's out-dated, being only intended for very old machines with less than 768MB of RAM (that generally won't be running windows 10, nor on modern hardware!)

Comment: Make sure the live usb is booted in uefi mode. Other posts here explain how.

Answer (score 0):

Your system must be UEFI given Win10 is already installed. In the case of UEFI installations, grub must be installed in the ESP partition. If you are using a single drive most likely this will be the first partition of the drive although it does not have to be in any special location. Run gparted and then you will see where the ESP partition resides.

During installation of Lubuntu, specify that you want to install grub into the ESP partition and that should fix the problem.

Here is what you would need to do;

1. create a liveUSB using the 64bit version of Lubuntu.
2. boot using liveUSB
3. run Lubuntu installation
4. provide requested responses till you get to the the screen where it will ask you select an installation option.
5. Select 'Something Else' option.
6. Now you need to select the partition where you want to install Lubuntu.
   Specify that you want to use this partition and select the option to format it.
7. Now click on the drop down menu where it asks you to specify where to install grub. Select the ESP partition. The ESP partition is around 100-200 Mbytes and should have the boot flag set.
8. Provide the rest of the information and when you restart the system you should see the grub menu where you can select Lubuntu or Windows as boot options.

Comment: Sorry (and thanks too), but how do I do it? Actually I'm very new to Linux. Been a Windows user since I was 5. How do I specify that I want to install it in the ESP partition?